# Cache of AFNetworking downloading file

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3

I'm downloading files using AFNetWorking.Its works well. And I stored files in "/Documents ".But the app downloaded again when I called this request again. Is there any solutions could cached these files like NSURLCache? When I request again and AF found it in folder, then read it without download again.

Here's my code.

```
AFHTTPSessionManager * manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

NSString * urlString = @"http://wiki.chinaxue.com/images/e/ee/super.docx";
NSString * string = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];

NSURLRequest * requesturl = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string]];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:requesturl progress:^ (NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {
    //
    NSLog(@"%lld---%lld",downloadProgress.totalUnitCount, downloadProgress.completedUnitCount);
} destination:^NSURL *_Nonnull(NSURL *_Nonnull targetPath, NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response) {

    NSString * DocumentPath = [KYCachedManager Share].documentPath; // filePath where download files stored

    NSString * documentName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",response.suggestedFilename];
    NSString *path = [DocumentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:documentName];

    MBLog(@"%@",path);

    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *_Nonnull response, NSURL * _Nullable filePath,NSError * _Nullable error) {
    MBLog(@"%@",filePath);
    complete(filePath);
}];
```

I tried to get "response.suggestedFilename" from downloadTask but failed.
another question: how could I get response.suggestedFilename without request? Then I could user fileManager to find it myself. if find read else request.

Answer (score 1):

AFNetworking takes advantage of the caching functionality already provided by NSURLCache but you need to setup.

set up cache as fellow and then use your own code for download it would work.

```
- (void)setupCache 
 {
       NSURLCache *urlCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:1024*1024*4 // 1MB mem 
                                         cachediskCapacity:1024*1024*5 // 5MB disk cache                                                                                                      
                                                        diskPath:nil];
      [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:urlCache];
 }
  //for lower iphone device like iphone 5
- (void)setupCache 
{
SDURLCache *urlCache = [[SDURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:1024*1024   // 1MB mem cache
                                                     diskCapacity:1024*1024*5 // 5MB disk cache
                                                         diskPath:[SDURLCache defaultCachePath]];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:urlCache];
}
```

Comment: I run the app by steps. I request first and a file exit, then I close Wi-Fi,request again, and the task run the complete block with error by network error. Is it prove the cached didn't work

Comment: its not a enough description to forecast any thing.

Comment: yeah,I tried your code. but how could I know it woked? I set "    manager.requestSerializer.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad;
"

Comment: is it uploading fine first time ? if yes call my code before creating your request to upload file.

Comment: I run your code at the initial of share class, File had been downloaded to my app, and I need to judge file exits first, The effect just like SDWebImage, Find the file by url from local first, if exist call complete block with file path.is it could solved by af? or I should code my self by file manager?

Comment: you dont need to code your own manager.It would check from cache first to before start download